# MySQL - How to put a result of Select Query to existing one?

Tags: mysql, select

Let's say i have two tables, Item and Transaction.

```
Table Item

ID  Name
1  Copper Wire
2  Bolt
3  Screw
4  Rubber Band 
5  Pipe

Table Transaction

Trans_ID Item_ID   Qty
T1          1       1
T1          2       2
T1          3       1
T1          4       2
T2          1       1
T2          3       2
```

I needs a select query showing a table like this

```
ID  Name          Trans_ID   QTY
1  Copper Wire      t2        1
2  Bolt
3  Screw            t2        2
4  Rubber Band 
5  Pipe
```

Is is possible to do it using MySql Select query alone?

Comment: Item.ID = 1 & Item.ID = 3 are involved in two transactions, so how do you want them to be listed? And why is there no entry against Item.ID = 2 & Item.ID = 4 in Trans_ID in your expected output? Not getting your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit join:

```
SELECT Item.ID, Name, Trans_ID, QTY
FROM Item, Transaction
WHERE Item.ID=Transaction.ID
```

(this query will not have the items without transaction)

Or explicit:

```
SELECT Item.ID, Name, Trans_ID, QTY
FROM Item
LEFT JOIN Transaction
ON Item.ID=Transaction.ID
```

(this one will, since it is a `LEFT JOIN` and the "left" is the `Item` table)